# How can I stop IE 7 from ignoring my width value and treating element as block when I set a padding?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

[Isolated test case](http://jsfiddle.net/LRpHq/18) (view in IE 7 or IE 8/9 in IE 7 mode)

Viewing this page in IE 7 is causing my width value to be ignored. If you remove the padding value, the width is properly applied, but when you add in the padding, it causes the entire page to grow, and it treats the padding almost as margin. The larger the width of the page, the larger the blank area to the right of the element. I've been unable to find which bug this is, and, more importantly, how to fix it. Has anyone seen this and does anyone know a solution?

Things I've tried so far:

- `zoom` fix
- `display: inline-block` (recommended for double vertical padding issue)
- It isn't `line-height` (it's a width issue...)

Screenshot of the issue:

This div should span the entire width of the page, and no more, but you'll notice the scrollbar here:
[image: IE 7 issue pre-scroll]
And the result of scrolling to the right:
[image: IE 7 issue post-scroll]
This should not be there.

Examining the element in the browser tools shows the width to be incorrectly the full width of the page, instead of the full width minus the padding.

Comment: Would you be able to link to some screenshots?  I'd like to see your bug, but I have no access to IE7.

Comment: @SethBattin Updated with screenshots. Also, you should be able to reproduce it with IE 8/9 in IE 7 mode.

Comment: Your question+comments makes it confusing what you *really* want. I'll bet it on a bit *too* oversimplified example. As to the concrete problem; if you replace `left` by `marginLeft` in the jQuery CSS setting, then the scrollbar will obviously go, but is the final result also what you *really* want?

Comment: As it's almost bed time, I posted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'll ignore the functional requirement and your comments on the other answers and just concentrate on the concrete problem.*

---

This IE7 specific problem is caused by using an offset (e.g. `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`) on a relatively positioned element. If you offsets a relatively positioned element, then it will basically still retain the whole space of its original position. Note that this doesn't happen when offsetting absolutely positioned element.

Before the `left` offset is been applied, the relatively positioned element is due to its width and and the right padding completely out of the viewport and hence a horizontal scollbar will be generated. After the `left` offset is applied on the relatively positioned element, you're basically leaving a space of the same size as the offset on the other side of the offset, still outside the viewport.

A bit sane webbrowser will during redrawing however discover that there's *nothing* visible outside the viewport and hence hide the scrollbar again. IE7, however, isn't that smart enough and retains the scrollbar.

After all, using `left` offset was technically been the wrong solution. You should in first place have used `margin-left` instead of `left`. Unlike the offset, the margin doesn't leave an empty space on the original position, but really pushes the whole element to the desired position.

So, here's how your script is been fixed:

```
$('#el').css({
    'width': document.body.scrollWidth - 200,
    'padding-right': 200,
    'margin-left': (-1 * (document.body.scrollWidth - 322) / 2) - 1
});
```

---

By the way, I wonder how that `float: left;` makes sense in this construct wherein you apparently want to simulate a 100% width. It'll probably be for other purposes not visible in the concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without using javascript for calculating width, and no padding, instead use `position: absolute`. Here's an updated fiddle. It will work in any browser

```
#el {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    min-height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LRpHq/7/

Comment: Resize the window to be smaller than the containing box, and then scroll to the right... it doesn't work. Also, with conflicting absolute position, `width: 100%` isn't needed.

Comment: You are right, width isn't needed there. For it to go all the way to the right I made it `postion:fixed`. Now it works well, as long as id doesn't bother you that if you scroll vertically it will remain there  http://jsfiddle.net/LRpHq/12/

Comment: It needs to stay where it is on the page. Also, that will mess things up like background images that are centered, or gradients or images that are set to cover/contain. This is why I'm using JS.

Comment: Sheesh, just add min-width: 320px; to it, and it solves the issue. But when will you ever have a screen smaller than 320px anyway? here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/LRpHq/17/

Comment: @EladR It also has the side effect of removing it from the flow of the page, so content below it won't be pushed down. And this is just an isolated example. It will be larger than 320px most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with a skeleton.css implementation. Specifically, my `#header` was taking the width of `body`, which took the width of `html`. The remaining content had a set-width of 978px. So when the window was smaller than 978, the background of the header would only render to the width of the viewport. i.e. - if you started the render at 500 wide, that's all the wider `#header` would get. Dragging a wider width of the viewport had no problems, but right scroll cut the header to the size of initial viewport.

My fix: `html,body { min-width:978px } /* your width may vary */`

Comment: I think what you're talking about is a different issue. Yours sounds like a display block element that was ending up smaller than the `body` because the `body` was shrinking with the window. My issue is actually that I have to break the bounds of my parent to stretch to the full width, and this is causing a bug in IE 7. Either way, however, setting the `min-width` on the `body` does not seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the original post as it was off by miles.

**edit:**

Tested in a sandboxed IE7 and it works. (what can i say, i go out of my way to get something perfect, also am new around here so that bounty would really help to be very honest) to also note that it works natively in IE7, IE8 and IE9, FF3.6, Opera 10 and should work in Safari with no problem, Chrome didn't get mentioned as it's my default browser and it works, no doubt about it.

Here is the JS:

```
function resize () {
$('#el').trigger('resize').width('100%');
}
resize();
```

and the CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#el {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    min-height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The `body` tag with a width doesn't seem to be the issue. See my comment on @Dawson's answer. But the setting the `overflow` property doesn't work either as it will cause issues if the window is smaller than 320 (or when I need a scrollbar because content is hidden).

Comment: @Ktash, thanks for that mate, you made a very good point, added that to the requirements list and built on from there, the scrollbar now appears if the window `width` is less than `320px` due to the `#container` div.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be fine with using Javascript, adjust your `resize()` function:

```
function resize () {
    $('#el').css({'width':$(window).width(),'position':'absolute','left':'0px'});
}
```

Comment: If the window is smaller than the document, the element will be smaller than the content. I want it to stretch the width of either the content or the window, whichever is bigger. That is what this code does. I'm specifically looking for how to address the bug that appears in IE 7 because of my method for doing this.

Comment: Ah. I'm afraid I was not aware of the desired result. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution  for similar problem [here](http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx). see if it can helps you too.